# Error opening Modal view: "The URL can't be shown"

Tags: trigger.io

This is the error that appears in the console:

> [WARNING] Modal webview error: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101
>   "The URL can’t be shown" UserInfo=0x8fee7e0
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http%3A%2F%2Fimgur.com%2F59tSD.jpg,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http%3A%2F%2Fimgur.com%2F59tSD.jpg,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The URL can’t be shown}

I get the same error when loading a local file with:

```
forge.tabs.open('about.html');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the former case it looks like you need to decode your url [decodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

In the later, you need to get the full path to the local file using [forge.tools.getURL](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/tools.html#geturl)

This should work:

```
forge.tools.getURL('about.html', function(url) {
    forge.tabs.open(url);
});
```